# Render different image format for browser

Tags: safari, cross-browser, webp

I'm developing a website and using .webp image format to reduce loading time. Chrome, Firefox, and new Opera versions are supporting this image format but not Safari. So should I have to render .jpeg format for it? if Yes. how to?
Or any other way to do it?